# Search a Binary Tree using Recursion in MIPS

Tags: mips

I need to write a section of code (the Search function) for the following binary tree search.

An pseudo-code example is given and reads :

```
The code for search could look like:
call store_path
##           if (value == 1)
##             return 1
##           if (left tree exists)
##             if (search(left tree, depth+1))
##              return 1
##           if (right tree exists)
##             return search(right tree, depth+1)
##           return 0
```

The whole MIPS code follows :

```
    .text       
        .globl __start 
__start:        # execution starts here

    la $a0,tree
    li $a1,0
    jal search  # search the tree

    jal print_path  # print the path
            # to the node with val=1
    li $v0,10
    syscall     # au revoir....


#------------------------------------------------
# store_path - store pointer at level n in the path
#   a0 - holds pointer to string
#   a1 - level to use in path
#------------------------------------------------
store_path:
    sll $t0,$a1,2   # each pointer is 4 bytes
    sw $a0,path($t0)# save pointer to the name
    addi $t0,$t0,4  # make the next entry 
    sw $0,path($t0) #  equal to 0.
    jr $ra


#------------------------------------------------
# print_path() - print the items stored in path 
#------------------------------------------------
print_path:
        li $t0,0        # i 
        sll $t1,$t0,2   # each pointer is 4 bytes
        lw $a0,path($t1)
next:   li $v0,4    
        syscall         # print path[i]
        addi $t0,$t0,1  # i++
        sll $t1,$t0,2   # each pointer is 4 bytes
        lw $a0,path($t1)
        beqz $a0,done
        move $t1,$a0
        la $a0,arrow
        li $v0,4
        syscall         # print "-->"
        move $a0,$t1
        b next
done:   la $a0,endl
        li $v0,4
        syscall         # print newline
        jr $ra
path:   .space 80

tree:   .word name0, node1, node2, 0
node1:  .word name1, node3, node4, 0
node2:  .word name2, node5, node6, 0
node3:  .word name3, node7, 0, 0
node4:  .word name4, node8, node9, 0
node5:  .word name5, 0, 0, 0
node6:  .word name6, node10, node11, 0
node7:  .word name7, 0, 0, 0
node8:  .word name8, 0, 0, 0
node9:  .word name9, node12, node13, 0
node10: .word name10, 0, 0, 0
node11: .word name11, 0, 0, 0
node12: .word name12, node14, node15, 0
node13: .word name13, 0, 0, 0
node14: .word name14, 0, 0, 1
node15: .word name15, node16, node17, 0
node16: .word name16, 0, 0, 0
node17: .word name17, 0, 0, 0

name0:  .asciiz "apple"
name1:  .asciiz "orange"
name2:  .asciiz "bananna"
name3:  .asciiz "pear"
name4:  .asciiz "plum"
name5:  .asciiz "peach"
name6:  .asciiz "nectarine"
name7:  .asciiz "pineapple"
name8:  .asciiz "grapefruit"
name9:  .asciiz "grape"
name10: .asciiz "melon"
name11: .asciiz "avocado"
name12: .asciiz "star"
name13: .asciiz "mango"
name14: .asciiz "passion"
name15: .asciiz "cantaloupe"
name16: .asciiz "watermelon"
name17: .asciiz "apricot"
    
endl:   .asciiz "\n"
arrow:  .asciiz "-->"
```

I have begun writing the Search Function :

```
jal store_path
      li $v0, 1
      beq $a0, 1, print_path
```

Any tips or tricks on how to implement the +1 depth and left and right tree searches would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Finish your pseudo code first; suggest writing it in C and testing to make sure it works. Small changes to your design/algorithm can mean *huge* changes in assembly, so much so that it is worth waiting until all algorithmic issues are resolved to translate into assembly.  Debugging design/algorithmic flaws in assembly is no fun when you're first learning assembly.  (When you have a working algorithm, you can be confident that the only source of errors is your translation to assembly, which is a much better situation.)

Answer (score 0):

1. $t0 is used to keep tracker of the number of integers to be pushed
   onto the stack. $t1 is used as a temporary variable to allow for
   easy swapping within the stack. $s0 is used to keep track of the
   address of the bottom of the stack. $s5 is used to hold the address
   above $sp; also used to traverse addresses if a swap occurs within
   the stack. $s6 is used to hold the value at $s5. $s7 is used to hold
   the address below $s5. $a1 holds the address of the bottom of the
   stack. $a2 holds the value of the incoming integer.

.data
numberOfInts:   .asciiz     "Number of Integers to Store: "
promptElement:  .asciiz     "\nEnter the integer to be found: "
promptInt:  .asciiz     "Enter Integer: "
printSort:  .asciiz     "Your Sorted Integers: "
invalidSize:    .asciiz     "\nYour Must Be Greater Than Zero.\n\n"
elementExists:  .asciiz     " exists in the stack.\n"
doesNotExist:   .asciiz     " does not exist in the stack.\n"
addspace:   .asciiz     " "
newLine:    .asciiz     "\n"
posInfinity:    .word       0x7FFFFFFF
`
.text
.globl main

main:                   # program entry

```
li  $t0, 0          # $a1 is the counter i = 0
```

initializeNumInts:
li  $v0, 4
la  $a0, numberOfInts
syscall             # "Number of Integers to Store: "
li  $v0, 5
syscall

```
ble $v0, $0, reinitialize

move    $s0, $v0
addi    $sp, $sp, -4        # Allocate space for the array size
sw  $s0, 0($sp)     # Store arraysize at the bottom of the stack
la  $a1, 0($sp)     # Remember the address of the bottom of the stack
```

insertToStack:
bge $t0, $s0, findElement

```
li  $v0, 4          
la  $a0, promptInt
syscall             # "Enter Integer: "
li  $v0, 5
syscall

jal preSortStack

addi    $t0, $t0, 1     # counter++

j   insertToStack
```

findElement:
li  $v0, 4
la  $a0, promptElement
syscall             # "Enter the Integer to be Found: "
li  $v0, 5
syscall

```
move    $v1, $v0        # Element to be found
addi    $a1, $a1, -4        # High of the Stack, Largest Integer, Highest Address
la  $a2, 0($sp)     # Low of the Stack, Smallest Integer, Lowest Address
jal search

beq $v0, $zero, elementDNE  # if ($v0 == 0)

li  $v0, 1
move    $a0, $v1
syscall
li  $v0, 4
la  $a0, elementExists
syscall 
j   terminate
```

elementDNE:

```
li  $v0, 1
move    $a0, $v1
syscall
li  $v0, 4
la  $a0, doesNotExist
syscall
```

terminate:
li  $v0, 10         # terminate the program
syscall

reinitialize:
li  $v0, 4
la  $a0, invalidSize
syscall
j   initializeNumInts

> Sort Stack Procedure  Adds elements into the stack from the
> stackpointer and then sorts them from least to greatest with the
> smallest element at the top of the stack.  $a1 -- Address of of the
> bottom of the stack.  $a2 -- Value of the element to be pushed onto
> the stack.

preSortStack:
move    $a2, $v0        # Place integer into argument
addi    $sp, $sp, -4        # Allocate space for incoming integer
la  $s5, 0($sp)     # Keeps track of addresses in the stack
sw  $a2, 0($sp)     # Push incoming integer onto the stack to account for first input

sortStack:
move    $s7, $s5        # $s7 keeps track of the address of previous $s5
addi    $s5, $s5, 4     # Go to the the address above $s5

```
beq $a1, $s5, exitSort  # If the address above the tracker is the bottom of the stack, exit the sort

lw  $s6, 0($s5)     # Get the value at the tracker
bgt $a2, $s6, swap      # if (incoming integer > value at below it in the stack), then swap values

sw  $a2, 0($sp)     # If the value above >= the incoming integer, push incoming integer onto stack
```

exitSort:
jr  $ra

swap:

```
move    $t1, $s6        # $t1 holds the value at tracker
sw  $a2, 0($s5)     # Store the incoming integer at the tracker
sw  $t1, 0($s7)     # Store $t1 at top of stack
move    $a2, $t1

j   sortStack       # Go back to sorting the stack in case there are smaller values above
```

Does Stack Contain Procedure
Traverses the stack to find an element in the stack.
$a1 -- Address of the HIGH index of the stack to be searched.
$a2 -- Address of the LOW index of the stack to be searched.
$v1 -- The value of the element to be found in the stack.

search:
ble $a2, $a1, checkCases    # test if (low <= high)
li  $v0, 0          # if not no portion of the stack exists.
jr  $ra         # return 0.

checkCases:

```
addu    $t0, $a2, $a1   
srl $t0, $t0, 1     # mid = (low + high) / 2

subu    $t1, $a1, $a2   
sra $t1, $t1, 2     # Number of Elements = (High - Low) / 4
addi    $t1, $t1, 1     # Align the number of elements to account for index 0.

andi    $t2, $t1, 1     # Check if number of elements is even or odd
beq $t2, $zero, even    # $t2 == 0, even number of elements have to be offset by 2 bits
j   saveValues
```

even:
addiu   $t0, $t0, -2        # Align on word boundary, mid address -2

saveValues:
lw  $t1, 0($t0)     # s[mid]

```
addi    $sp, $sp, -12
sw  $ra, 8($sp)     
sw  $a1, 4($sp)     # Save High Index
sw  $a2, 0($sp)     # Save Low Index

beq $t1, $v1, found     # if (s[mid] == val)
blt $t1, $v1, lowerStack
j   upperStack
```

lowerStack:
addi    $a2, $t0, 4     # Low = mid + 1
jal search
j   checkIfFound

upperStack:
addi    $a1, $t0, -4        # High = mid - 1
jal search

checkIfFound:
lw  $a2, 0($sp)     # Low Index
lw  $a1, 4($sp)     # High Index
lw  $ra, 8($sp)
addi    $sp, $sp, 12

```
jr  $ra
```

found:
li  $v0, 1          # if portion of the stack exist
jr  $ra         # return 1.
`

Comment: being new to stack overflow! i had trouble formatting the code. but this might help you..
remove the comments too